# How to apply Cauchy's Residue Theorem to a triangle?

Tags: complex-analysis

Say I have a triangle with vertices $(-5, 5, 17i)$ and a function $f(z)$ with a residue of $-\dfrac{i}{5}$. Would I apply the residue theorem once and end up with $2 \pi i \cdot -\dfrac{i}{5}$ or would I apply it on every line segment so $2 \pi i \cdot -\dfrac{i}{5}$ + $2 \pi i \cdot -\dfrac{i}{5}$ + $2 \pi i \cdot -\dfrac{i}{5}$?

Comment: Where is the singularity?  Is it interior to the triangle?

Comment: Yes, it is inside the triangle.

Comment: What do Cauchy's Integral Theorem and the residue theorem state?

Comment: I just wasn't sure if the corners of the triangle meant that the theorem couldn't be used.

Comment: The contour only needs to be rectifiable.  And a triangle is surely a rectifiable contour.

Answer (score 1):

You would apply it once with the contour being the entire triangle. It doesn't make sense to apply it to each segment of the triangle because the theorem is for closed contours.